# How to hardcode a cluster ID in EMR step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I am trying to create EMR step-functions where I want to specify my EMR cluster that is always running. All the examples I've come across online, tell you how to create a cluster and then terminate it once the job is done.

My EMR step function is as follows:

```
{
  "Comment": "My EMR Step",
  "StartAt": "Config_Meta",
  "States": {
    "Config_Meta": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId.$": "j-4ABCDEFGHIK",
        "Step": {
          "Name": "Config_Meta",
          "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
          "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
              "bash",
              "-c",
              "source /home/hadoop/.bashrc && spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --executor-cores 4 --driver-cores 4 --executor-memory 19g --driver-memory 19g --num-executors 27 --conf spark.default.parallelism=100 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=9g --conf spark.shuffle.io.retryWait=180s --conf spark.network.timeout=500s --conf maximizeResourceAllocation=true s3://path/config_meta.py"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Where I specified my cluster ID in `"ClusterId.$": "j-4ABCDEFGHIK"`. However, I get the following error when I try saving it.

> The value for the field 'ClusterId.$' must be a valid JSONPath

Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the `$` from the cluster variable definition.

Change

```
"ClusterId.$": "j-4ABCDEFGHIK"
```

to

```
"ClusterId": "j-4ABCDEFGHIK"
```

Comment: can be run a cluster stopped only with id in step functions ? or is necessary create/run it before

Comment: @CristiánVargasAcevedo
You can write step functions to create, and then stop/terminate an EMR cluster:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-emr.html